# did our chatroom get removed?

Tags: discussion, chat

Regarding: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/324/the-locker-room

I was the last guy to post in it ~4 months ago, it looks like it got frozen/unfrozen, and then [this](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32660/discussion-between-brondahl-and-alec) happened 9 days ago. Also, I think "Chat" used to be in the main navigation somewhere.

Just curious if it's officially gone, and basically what's going on with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is going on with it, and that's the problem. The Locker Room is still there, but it's empty.  I don't know why JohnP had that freeze/unfreeze incident (maybe it was a misclick) but that doesn't mean much compared to the low interest in the room.

The link to chat, along with a link to meta, has been moved from the top navigation to the "site switcher" dropdown. Here it is:

[image: switcher]

This change happened [two years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207420/the-new-top-bar-is-out-on-meta-consider-it-a-beta).

The [discussion room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32660/discussion-between-brondahl-and-alec) is something that is created automatically when a moderator moves some comments to chat. Expect that discussion room to freeze in a few days. If you expand the list to [show frozen rooms](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&nohide=true&host=fitness.stackexchange.com), you'll see  the creation of such rooms is nothing unusual.

Comment: No, it wasn't a misclick. I wasn't sure if being a moderator on one site gave me chat room control on this site as well. Evidently that answer is yes. :)